# Universal Covering Group of particular quotient space?

Tags: general-topology, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, covering-spaces

We know that the universal cover of $SO(2)$ is $\mathbb{R}$ and the unitary group $U(2)$ has universal cover $SU(2) \times \mathbb R$, i,e. $\widetilde{U(2)}=SU(2) \times \mathbb R$ and $\widetilde{SO(2)}=\mathbb R$ . Then, so the space $ \widetilde{U(2)}/\widetilde{SO(2)}$ identify with which space? i.e.,
$$ \widetilde{U(2)}/\widetilde{SO(2)} = SU(2) \times \mathbb R/ \mathbb R = ???$$
Moreover, is what has $ \widetilde{U(2)/SO(2)}= \widetilde{U(2)}/\widetilde{SO(2)} ?$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\widetilde{U(2)}/\widetilde{SO(2)}$ doesn't make sense because $\widetilde{SO(2)}$ is not a subset of $\widetilde{U(2)}$, right? There are probably multiple, non-equivalent ways to embed one into another.

Comment: @ freakish, if it makes sense, my problem is that $SU(2) \times \mathbb R/ \mathbb R= SU(2)  $ or what?

Comment: Again, that deosn't make sense: $\mathbb{R}$ **is not** a subset of $SU(2)\times\mathbb{R}$. If you embed it as $r\mapsto (0, r)$ (i.e. onto the second coordinate) then yes. But if you embed $\mathbb{R}$ into the first coordinate $SU(2)$ or mix coordinates (e.g. $r\mapsto (f(r), g(r))$ with both $f,g$ nontrivial) then no.

Comment: $SO(2)$ is a subset of $U(2)$, and there is a projection $\widetilde{U(2)}\to U(2)$, but since $SO(2)$ is contractible within $U(2)$ its preimage in $\widetilde{U(2)}$ is just another $SO(2)$, not $\widetilde{SO(2)}$. Thus, you can't automatically say $\widetilde{SO(2)}$ is a subgroup of $\widetilde{U(2)}$. You will have to *choose* an embedding $\widetilde{SO(2)}\to\widetilde{U(2)}$ and the answer to your question depends on that choice.